# How to obtain the mean-matrix from a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, permutation

I have a list of 100 50*50 matrices in R stored in a variable called all_permutations.

```
> str(all_permutations)
List of 100
 $ : num [1:50, 1:50] 0 0.00972 0.34989 0 0.0019 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
 $ : num [1:50, 1:50] 0 0.00972 0.34989 0 0.0019 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
```

Is there an elegant way to obtain the mean of all these matrices without constructing double for-loops to get the average for each index across all 100 matrices? Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what "the mean of all these matrices" is? is it the mean of position [1,1] of each matrix for example?

Comment: I apologize, @Jeremy. I meant that I could get the mean of 100 values for each of the indices of the 50*50 matrix. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the averages of the elements in each position, you would want to sum up the elements of `all_permutations` and then divide by the number of elements.

If you were typing this out, you would do something like:

```
(all_permutations[[1]] + all_permutations[[2]] + ... ) / length(all_permutations)
```

Luckily, the `Reduce` function can save you a lot of typing (or, more likely, a `for` loop):

```
Reduce("+", all_permutations) / length(all_permutations)
```